# How to pass param from HtmlHelper(CakePHP)

Tags: php, cakephp

I use cakePhp framework and i want to pass param from HtmlHelper to controller.
I use piece of code

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link(
'Dashboard',
array(
    'controller' => 'dashboards',
    'action' => 'index',
    'full_base' => true
),
'data'=>array('some data')
); ?>
```

and from controller i want to get the $data attachment.
If it is possible, how can i do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's simple :

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link(
'Dashboard',
array(
    'controller' => 'dashboards',
    'action' => 'index',
    $param_value,
    $another_one
),
); ?>
```

you don't have to specify the name of the param just the value , if you have many params so you have to pay attention to their order , in the controller you can get the param like that :

```
public function index($param_name = null , $another_one =null) {
 print $param_name;
 print $another_one;

}
```